# Symfony Session & Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony, fetch-api

so I'll try to be explicit:

I have a middleware in my symfony's project which is supposed to increment the number of connection attempts in the session variable (RequestStack::getSession()) which works quite well in Postman, the problem being that it does not work with Fetch, the returned session seems empty after "debug". I suspect the PHPSESSID is not stored in my Fetch when the session is created by Symfony

Middleware

```php
public function __construct(JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder, RequestStack $requestStack, ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->jwtEncoder = $jwtEncoder;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): JsonResponse
    {
        // debug
        // return new JsonResponse([$this->session->all(), 'error' => true, 'message' => 'Authentication failed'], 401);

        // check if login is restricted
        $this->loginResricted();
        
        // increment attempt in session
        $this->incrementAttempt($request);

        return new JsonResponse(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Authentication failed'], 401);
    }
```

I tried to debug the session but nothing in output, but I need to keep the user session alive till he is trying to login

Comment: Is the fetch request cross-origin? And if so, have you set `credentials` in the fetch options correctly?

Comment: Actually my fetch looks like this:

`fetch(url, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-api-key": "XXX",
    },
credentials: "include"
body: JSON.stringify(data)
});`

CORS is enabled, and each others request are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found an alternative to my problem if someone is looking for it:

Two ways:

- you can store it to your database (more secure I think)
- or in Symfony's Cache Component

This is my scheme if you are interested:

UserAttempt

```json
{
  "id": int,
  "ip": string,
  "logins": array,
  "delay": int,
  "created_at": datetime,
  "updated_at": datetime
}
```

You will be able to track user attempts based on his IP.

Comment: Not sure what you have in that `logins` array, just make sure you don't store any user and password in plaintext. ;)

Comment: That's the payload for my JWT, in logins we have only mail tested by the user, each attempt will be saved for a singular IP, so plaintext can be use cause logins maybe not exist